# OrderSubquery combined with second table

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have two tables:

```
1) product data
2) sales stats of these products
```

In table 2 I have the sales stats for each product per day.  I want to get the most-sold products from the last 30 days. I realised this with the following query:

```
SELECT sku
FROM    prod_history
WHERE insert_date >= SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 31 DAY)
GROUP BY sku
ORDER BY SUM(number_of_orders) DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

This query takes about 4.5 seconds.

Now I want to connect this query result with the product data table (1).

I use the following query for this, but the result I got was not correct.
**The results I received were often not the most-sold products.**

```
SELECT `prod_combined`.`sku`, `prod_combined`.`titel`, `prod_combined`.`preis_vk`, `prod_combined`.`link` 
FROM `prod_combined` 
WHERE (prod_combined.sku IN 
    (SELECT prod_combined.sku 
        FROM (SELECT sku FROM prod_history WHERE insert_date >= SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 31 DAY) 
        GROUP BY sku ORDER BY SUM(number_of_orders) DESC LIMIT 0 , 10 
     ) q 
     JOIN prod_combined ON prod_combined.sku = q.sku ) 
) 
AND (aktiv = 1) LIMIT 5
```

Is there any way to get the needed result in one query?

Kind regards,
Max

Comment: While your title is appealing to certain guys' ego, I think it ought to be changed to reflect your question better..

Comment: done ;) hopefully, i will find somebody now ;)

Comment: @MaxSchindler I have removed "MySQL" from the title too ... people already know its a MySQL question as you have tagged it as such ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inner query gets ten best selling products within last month, but outer query limits only five without any ordering. It should be fixed if you limit inner query to five.

Here is join version of the query:

```
SELECT `prod_combined`.`sku`, `prod_combined`.`titel`, `prod_combined`.`preis_vk`, `prod_combined`.`link`
FROM `prod_combined` 
INNER JOIN `prod_history`
ON prod_combined.sku = prod_history.sku
WHERE prod_history.insert_date >= SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 31 DAY) 
  AND prod_combined.aktiv = 1
GROUP BY `prod_combined`.`sku`, `prod_combined`.`titel`, `prod_combined`.`preis_vk`, `prod_combined`.`link`
ORDER BY SUM(prod_history.number_of_orders) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Thanks! It works exactly how i wanted.
I know that my own query did not work correctly, but it was much faster. Is there anything i can do, to get a faster result?

Your Query takes about 34 seconds ;(

Comment: Did you try to put LIMIT 5 in your original inner query?

Comment: You`re right. Again ;)
I changed it, so that both limits are equal and so it works.

Answer (score 0):

I just think your order of activity is off in your second query there... i.e. you begin with a product and then qualify it. If I were going to go that route, I'd use use a where not exists clause instead; x sku's with a count greater that my product's count do not exist.

However, is there a reason you cannot just join your product data to your original?

```
SELECT a.sku, a.titel, a.preis_vk, a.link, SUM(b.number_of_orders) as number_of_orders 
FROM prod_combined as a inner join 
     prod_history as b on a.sku = b.sku
WHERE b.insert_date >= SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 31 DAY)
GROUP BY a.sku, a.titel, a.preis_vk, a.link
ORDER BY SUM(b.number_of_orders) DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Or along those lines.